# How to "reuse" a regex find and replace in Vim

Tags: command-line, vim, batch, regex

I have a plain text file with entries as

```
firstAuthorLastName_titleFirstWord_YYYY
```

that I change to

```
firstAuthorLastNameYYYYtitleFirstWord
```

with the following `s//` command in Vim.^[1]

```
%s/\([a-z]\+\)_\([a-z]\+\)_\([0-9]\{4}\)/\1\3\2/g
```

But I want to do this command over and over again. It seems that I should be able to do this with a Windows batch script and the `-c` flag to `gvim.exe`. But I can't get it to work.

I have a Windows batch script with the following.

```
gvim -c "%s/\([a-z]\+\)_\([a-z]\+\)_\([0-9]\{4}\)/\1\3\2/g" herron.bib
```

But I get the message `E486: Pattern not found: \([a-z]\+\)_\([a-z]\+\)_\([0-9]\{4}\)`. Is there a way to reuse/automate this `s//` command? I know that I can up arrow through my ex command history, but I'd like something a little more permanent and reliable.

[^1] FWIW, this is a BibTeX .bib file that I export from [Zotero](http://www.zotero.org/). Further downstream I use [vim-pandoc](https://github.com/vim-pandoc) to write notes in markdown. The underscores make it a little more difficult to use the vim-pandoc "tidy" function, so I remove them. I update the .bib several times a week and re-export it from Zotero, so I also need to run this regex several times a week.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong, and apparently the pattern is correctly passed to Vim, so it *should* work :-(

### Alternatives

Unless you really need special Vim capabilities, you're probably better off using *non-interactive tools* like `sed`, `awk`, or Perl / Python / Ruby / *your favorite scripting language here*.

That said, you can use Vim non-interactively:

### Silent Batch Mode

For very simple text processing (i.e. using Vim like an enhanced 'sed' or 'awk', maybe just benefitting from the enhanced regular expressions in a `:substitute` command), use *Ex-mode*.

```
REM Windows
call vim -N -u NONE -n -es -S "commands.ex" "filespec"
```

Note: silent batch mode (`:help -s-ex`) messes up the Windows console, so you may have to do a `cls` to clean up after the Vim run.

### Vim alternatives

Based on your description, it's not entirely clear whether you want full automation, or just easier recall. If you don't mind applying the command manually (but quickly) from within Vim, how about:

a) a custom command

```
:command! TidyNames %s/\([a-z]\+\)_\([a-z]\+\)_\([0-9]\{4}\)/\1\3\2/g
```

b) a custom mapping

```
:nnoremap <Leader>tn :%s/\([a-z]\+\)_\([a-z]\+\)_\([0-9]\{4}\)/\1\3\2/g<CR>
```

Both of these can be placed into your `~/.vimrc`, or (with `<buffer>` modifier) in a filetype-specific `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim`.

Comment: Thanks! `command!` did the trick! Thanks for the thorough lesson and I'll check out all of these. But you're right, "easier recall" is the best way to say this. Thanks!